# How to read a char in Vala?

Tags: vala

I'm programming in Vala language and I've a problem: I don't know how to read a char (although I know how to read a string and an integer).

```
string name = stdin.read_line();
int maximum = int.parse(stdin.read_line()); 
char option = ????;
```

One option is using scanf(), but if I use it I have problems during execution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to read a single character from a GLib.FileStream, you can use [GLib.FileStream.getc](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.FileStream.getc.html), which "reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error."  Actually, [GLib.FileStream.read_line is implemented using getc](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/vapi/glib-2.0.vapi?id=bd1ec7117a8acbf1f4acb163a82a10aacc7ac89f#n3131).  So, the "????" in your question would be something like `(char) stdin.getc()`.

If you are trying to interact with a user, note that input is typically buffered by the terminal until the end of a line.  If you want to get a character immediately after the user presses a key you'll need to use something like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (for which Vala bindings are distributed with valac).